# How to cleanly stub out REST client when in test environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, testing, rspec

I have a basic model like the following

```
class MyModel
    def initialize(attrs)   
        @attrs = attrs
        @rest_client = Some::REST::Client.new 
    end

    def do_a_rest_call(some_str)
      @rest_client.create_thing(some_str)
    end
end
```

For testing purposes, I don't want @rest_client to make remote calls. Instead, in a test environment, I just want to make sure that `@rest_client` gets called with a specific `some_str` when it goes through certain branches of code.

In an ideal world, I'd have an assertion similar to:

`expect(my_model_instance).to.receive(do_a_rest_call).with(some_str)` where in the test I will pass some_str to make sure it's the right one.

What's the best way to do this using RSpec 3.8 and Rails 5.2.2?

Comment: I don't know about the "best way". (How do you quantify "best"?) But, I use [webmock](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock) and that strikes me as a pretty not so terrible way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution that should work without any additional gems:

```
let(:rest_client_double) { instance_double(Some::REST::Client, create_thing: response) }

it 'sends get request to the RestClient' do
  allow(Some::REST::Client).to receive(:new).and_return(rest_client_double)

  MyModel.new(attrs).do_a_rest_call(some_str)

  expect(rest_client_duble).to have_received(:create_thing).with(some_str).once
end
```

Basically, you are creating a double for REST client.
Then, you make sure that when calling `Some::REST::Client.new` the double will be used (instead of real REST client instance).

Finally, you call a method on your model and check if double received given message.

Comment: what is the value for in the create_thing argument?

Comment: In the first line? There, you define the method name and response that should be returned. So, if you will call `Some::REST::Client.new.create_thing` you will get `response`.